# A sql query not working properly

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a sql query that will shows up who has most `refereal_code` used in the table `refereal_system` based in who we will do somethings to receive the `` `p`.`name` ``

Here is a few steps how that should work:

1- Check what is the refereal_code who has most used in `refereal_system` and check in `accounts` who has the `refereal_code` WHERE the `refereal_system`.`invited_received` needs to be equal than one.

2- There is a result? Okay, good, who was? Let's uses his ID with `accounts`.`id`

3- Now we will check the if `players`.`account_id` is equal than `accounts`.`id`

4- We found something? Okay, good return who has most `players`.`experience` in the `players`.`account_id`.

5- Shows up the `players`.`name` with a DESC LIMIT 10.

I tried create, and I got this but I got stucked in the steps 1, 4

```
SELECT
    `p`.`name`,
    COUNT(`ref`.`refereal_code`) AS `count`
        FROM `refereal_system` as ref
            LEFT JOIN `accounts` AS a
                ON `a`.`refereal_code` = `ref`.`refereal_code`
            LEFT JOIN `players` p 
                ON `p`.`account_id` = `a`.`id`
            WHERE `ref`.`invited_received` = 1
                GROUP BY `ref`.`refereal_code`
                    ORDER BY `ref`.`refereal_code` DESC LIMIT 10
```

With this query it is returning like this

[image]

**The query result should return 1 and not 2 because ** `invited_received` **is equal than 1 just one time**

[image]

Comment: Try `COUNT(DISTINCT ref.refereal_code)`

Comment: @Barmar It worked, but now it is missing the step 4, how to select the player name who was the most experience in the account?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're saying there, but I don't think you can do it in the same query, or maybe you need to join your query with another query that orders by experience.

Comment: Can you show all the input tables and what the desired result of all 5 steps is?

Comment: Accounts - https://prnt.sc/i4j1lo // Refereal_system - https://prnt.sc/i4j211 // Players - https://prnt.sc/i4j2fj . In theses images you can see all input tables. What do you think that I should do?

Comment: Please put the sample data in the question. And do it as plain text so it can be copied and pasted for testing.

Comment: What about the desired result?